# Soundcloud current track Info

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, soundcloud

Concerning [the following site](http://cosystudios.com/thecosystudio.co.uk/thecosystudio.html)

Pretty simple, but none the less I seem to be falling at the first hurdle on this.

Using the following code currently to try and obtain a track name and artist from the currently active soundcloud player (of which there are 4 ,with the class SCiframe)

```
$(function () {
    var $iframeElement = document.getElementsByClassName('SCiframe');
    var $widgets = SC.Widget(iframeElement);
    widgets.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function () {
        widgets.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function () {
            // get information about currently playing sound
            widgets.getCurrentSound(function (currentSound) {
                $('#trackInfo').append('Current Track: ' + currentSound.get('') + '');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

for one, the console is registering 'iframeElement is not defined' as an inital error.
But all in all, I cant seem to get any useful data out of this to process.

Where am i going wrong here?

Kindest regards to the community.

Answer (score 0):

You have the variable names incorrect, they have "$" at the begining,

```
$(function () {
    var $iframeElement = document.getElementsByClassName('SCiframe');
    var $widgets = SC.Widget($iframeElement);
    $widgets.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function () {
        $widgets.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function () {
                // get information about currently playing sound
                $widgets.getCurrentSound(function (currentSound) {
                $('#trackInfo').append('Current Track: ' + currentSound.get('') + '');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

getElementsByClassName returns an array of results. So if there is only one iframe with "SCiframe" classname, you should pass first index of $iframeElement as paramater in SC.Widget, try this,

```
$(function () {
    var $iframeElement = document.getElementsByClassName('SCiframe');
    var $widgets = SC.Widget($iframeElement[0]);
    $widgets.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function () {
        $widgets.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function () {
            // get information about currently playing sound
            $widgets.getCurrentSound(function (currentSound) {
                $('#trackInfo').append('Current Track: ' + currentSound.get('') + '');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: ok, yes true and this does solve the simple error. But the code still returns nothing.
I've added in "alert('Current Track: ' + currentSound.get('') + '');" To see if i can get anything out but nothing happens so evidently its not even getting this far.

Im also now getting the error:
a.contentDocument is undefined

Comment: I added in a few alerts...
$(function() {
     var $iframeElement = document.getElementsByClassName('SCiframe');
     var $widgets = SC.Widget($iframeElement);
     $widgets.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
       alert('ready');
      $widgets.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function() {
       alert('bind');
            // get information about currently playing sound
             $widgets.getCurrentSound(function(currentSound) { 
                $('#trackInfo').append('Current Track: ' + currentSound.get('') + '');
        alert('Current Track: ' + currentSound.get('') + '');

Comment: None of them are set off so the bind function isnt even being called .

Comment: I had a horrible feeling that might cause some issue.

Problem is and the reason why I chose a class is because there are 4 separate players, that I was hoping would all share the same API for playback.

was kind of hoping that clever ole jQuery might just take the full array and process them all together as one.

Could I possibly make some sort of loop to iterate through each and attach the same listener to each? or just use jQuery .each() some way to catch all?..

Comment: the [0] ammendment does indeed allow the code to continue , I get my alert after READY is executed and another alert after the BIND is successful.
But the code still hangs on the currsound.get part, with the console error..
currentSound.get is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$('#trackInfo').append('Current Track: ' + currentSound.get('') + '');